# How to provide mock filters for unit testing

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a Controller that has this line of code

```
 var formattedDate= $filter('date')(dateColName,short);
```

I am trying unit test this controller and I am not clear on how to mock the date filter in my code.

Comment: Do you *really* need to mock the date filter?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add 'Filter' to the end of your filter name when mocking a filter in Angular, as Angular stores filter like services, but adds 'Filter' to the end. Try this for example:

```
var mockFilter = function() {
    return 'whatyouwantittoreturn';
};

beforeEach(function() {
    module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('dateFilter', mockFilter );
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I made the stupid mistake of putting this after my inject() and got a warning, so FYI to those that use this, put it BEFORE your inject() or it'll bark at'cha.